# Bluetooth mouse random lag

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Cursor randomly freezes. Seems to lag more often when mouse moves often

Mouse MX Anywhere 2S

Ubuntu 21.10
bluetoothd 5.60
blueman-manager 2.2.2

Blueman applet disabled at startup
USB suspend disabled. GRUB: usbcore.autosuspend=-1

$ lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:c123 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

$ lshw

```
*-usb
 description: Bluetooth wireless interface
 product: Bluetooth Radio
 vendor: Realtek
 physical id: 3
 bus info: usb@3:3
 version: 0.00
 serial: 00e04c000001
 capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.00
 configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

$ btmgmt extinfo

```
Primary controller (hci0,USB)
hci0:   Primary controller
    addr 30:C9:AB:E1:23:A4 version 10 manufacturer 93
    supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr phy-configuration wide-band-speech 
    current settings: powered ssp br/edr le secure-conn
```

$ cat /etc/bluetooth/input.conf

```
# Configuration file for the input service

# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
#IdleTimeout=30
IdleTimeout=0

# Enable HID protocol handling in userspace input profile
# Defaults to false (HIDP handled in HIDP kernel module)
UserspaceHID=true

# Limit HID connections to bonded devices
# The HID Profile does not specify that devices must be bonded, however some
# platforms may want to make sure that input connections only come from bonded
# device connections. Several older mice have been known for not supporting
# pairing/encryption.
# Defaults to false to maximize device compatibility.
ClassicBondedOnly=true

# LE upgrade security
# Enables upgrades of security automatically if required.
# Defaults to true to maximize device compatibility.
#LEAutoSecurity=true
```

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf - I think is default one
https://pastebin.com/VGKQ3BHe

$ sudo cat "/var/lib/bluetooth/30:C9:AB:E1:23:A4/E6:F0:49:CE:56:0B/info"

```
[sudo] password for hc: 
[General]
Name=MX Anywhere 2S
Appearance=0x03c2
AddressType=static
SupportedTechnologies=LE;
Trusted=true
Blocked=false
WakeAllowed=true
Services=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d;

[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=9
Latency=44
#Latency=0 - no effect
Timeout=216

[IdentityResolvingKey]
Key=22435F803EA72D1D13634BBAC2FEB75B

[LocalSignatureKey]
Key=2D6E094C34CD3A001F881E4A91D7A093
Counter=0
Authenticated=false

[LongTermKey]
Key=20F89B4CE70335FE7CC0D9F73C46F817
Authenticated=0
EncSize=16
EDiv=55153
Rand=9913277286849690115

[DeviceID]
Source=2
Vendor=1133
Product=45082
Version=3
```

$ sudo cat "/var/lib/bluetooth/30:C9:AB:E1:23:A4/E6:F0:49:CE:56:0B/attributes"

```
[1]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=1800
EndGroupHandle=7

[8]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=1801
EndGroupHandle=11

[12]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=180A
EndGroupHandle=26

[27]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=180F
EndGroupHandle=30

[31]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=1812
EndGroupHandle=62

[63]
UUID=00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Value=00010000000010008000011F2000046D
EndGroupHandle=65535
```

journalctl output
https://pastebin.com/kiJTTiqz

$ sudo btmon --write ~/hcitrace.snoop | tee ~/hcitrace.txt
https://pastebin.com/pHQYtFcq